Encoding characters back to string in php
I have following string:
ab"wefdty?'aaavvv

After submitting the data it shows like this :
ab&#039;wefdty?&quot;aaavvv
I tried with htmlspecialCharacters, htmlentities but it won't work. How should I get the original text back?

How do you pass/retrieve data? Please add the necessary code that would help people help you.

@Mr.Kenneth Accepting input from react UI textbox and retrieve using API.

You should use the html_entity_decode function :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php
echo html_entity_decode("ab&#039;wefdty?&quot;aaavvv");


You can use following PHP functions as both are valid approaches:
html_entity_decode()
htmlspecialchars_decode()

But htmlspecialchars_decode() is limited as it only decodes some characters:
(&, " (double quote), '< (less than), and ' (greater than)). If your encoded string includes other HTML entities, html_entity_decode() would be more comprehensive.
To decode entities back to their original characters in PHP, you can do it in following way:
$encodedString = 'ab&#039;wefdty?&quot;aaavvv';
$decodedString = html_entity_decode($encodedString, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
echo $decodedString;

